# Count number of colored cells in range using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a code for counting number of colored cell. Can you please advice how to extend range?
Basically I need to count colored cells columns range like ("A:Z") and nRowIndex = 2 To 100?

```
Sub CountCellsWithBackgroundColor()
  Dim nRowIndex As Integer, nCellNumber As Integer

  'Go through the range
  Worksheets("Report_Rule_S").Activate
  For nRowIndex = 2 To 100
    If Range("E" & nRowIndex).Interior.ColorIndex <> -4142 Then 'need to do somthing like Range("A:Z")
      nCellNumber = nCellNumber + 1
    End If
  Next nRowIndex

  ' Output the result
  Worksheets("cover").Range("B12") = nCellNumber
End Sub
```

Comment: Are they colored manually or via conditional formatting?

Comment: `For each cl in Worksheets("Report_Rule_S").Range("A2:Z100").cells` then `If cl.Interior.ColorIndex <> -4142`

Comment: cells are colored via another macro, with specific rule. as a result i have a range with colored cells, and I need to count, how mach it in range

Answer (score 2):

You can put all of this in one single For-Each loop:

```
Dim aCell As Range

Dim cellNumber As Integer
cellNumber = 0

For Each aCell In Range("A2:Z100").Cells:
  If aCell.Interior.ColorIndex <> -4142 Then
    cellNumber = cellNumber + 1
  End If
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

my comments below

```
Sub CountCellsWithBackgroundColor()
  Dim nRowIndex As Integer, nCellNumber As Integer
  'Go through the range
  Worksheets("Report_Rule_S").Activate
  For Each cl In Worksheets("Report_Rule_S").UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells
    If cl.Interior.ColorIndex <> -4142 Then
      nCellNumber = nCellNumber + 1
    End If
  Next cl
  'Output the result
  Worksheets("cover").Range("B12") = nCellNumber
End Sub
```